# What Cocoa control to use for picking a directory

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm writing an OS X application that generates lots of files and saves them in a user-selected directory. I want to use a directory dropdown similar to what you find in Transmission. What control is that?

[image: What control is this?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NSPathControl with Style Pop Up.

[image]

EDIT: **I experimented with this and finally did some tweak/hacking**

This contains a push button with these settings : No title, Unchecked Refuses first Responder and Unchecked Enabled. NSPath control is drawn on top of this. Just to look like a pop up button.

Find [working model here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6036018/pathcontrol-popup-style-36k?da=y).

[image]

Comment: Yes this seems to be what I'm looking for. But it's flat by default. How do I make it look like a dropdown, with a border around it and such?

Comment: If you want to use dropdown you can use it. If you want to use NSPathControl is that way, you need to customize it by subclassing.

Comment: I want to use NSPathControl. I just want to make it have a border so that it looks like the one in Transmission. How do I do that? You mentioned subclassing but I don't see anything in NSPathControl that would allow me to add a border. Or are you suggesting that I override its paint method (or something like that; still new to Cocoa) and paint a border myself?

Comment: @Hongli: Please check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478252/how-do-i-make-an-nspathcontrol-look-like-other-dropdown-boxes

Comment: @Hongli: Thanks for accepting this, but no up vote? Dint you like the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSPopupButton.
[image]

Take a look at [source code](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser#trunk)(PrefWindow.xib and PrefsController.m) of [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/).

Comment: Yes of course, he can use popup as well. But cocoa gives you NSPathControl object with many methods for quick development. So why not to use that one?

Comment: NSPathControl doesn't look like a Cocoa dropdown.